# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_registered_models' django-cms 3.2

Tags: django, upgrade, django-cms, reversion

I am upgrading Django 1.4 to 1.8. I am getting error like this 
"revision_manager._registered_models[model_key] = registration_info
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_registered_models'"

It's coming from this file "site-packages\cms\utils\reversion_hacks.py", line 40, in register_draft_only".

I have older version are
1. django-cms 2.3.8
2. reversion 1.6
3. django 1.4
and 
New version are
1. django-cms 3.2.0
2. reversion 1.10.0
3. django 1.8.7

Anybody have a solution? please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

reversion 1.10 is not supported, please install `django-reversion>=1.8,<1.9`

Comment: Could you kindly add a reference to where you get this information from?  Thank you!